# Combining maybe as monad lines into something more general

Tags: haskell

I'm writing some mysql-simple database code, and I'm making my datatypes members of the QueryResults type class to make it easy to unmartial them.

But I'm ending up with a lot of functions like:

```
data FullName {
  first_name :: String,
  middle_name :: String,
  last_name :: String
} deriving Show

newtype UID = UID Integer deriving Show

go :: [(String, String)] -> Maybe FullName
go fvs = do
  first  <- lookup "first_name" fvs
  middle <- lookup "middle_name" fvs
  last   <- lookup "last_name" fvs
  return $ FullName first middle last

go :: [(String, String)] -> Maybe UID
go fvs = do
  uid <- lookup "uid" fvs
  return $ UID (read uid)
```

where lookup just returns (Maybe a).  Some of these data types have a dozen columns in them, so this gets tedious.

So there are a lot of datatypes like this and I would like to be able to write a function I would call like this:

```
go RealName ["first_name","middle_name","last_name"] fvs
go UID ["uid"] fvs
```

but I have no idea what the type of such a thing should be, or how I would go about it.  Maybe this isn't even possible.

Comment: `UID` takes an `Integer`, but your (second) `go` function appears to give it a `String`. (I presume the two `go` functions are supposed to have different names.)

Comment: Your first definition of `go` has type `[(String, String)] -> Maybe FullName` and your second definition has type `[(String, String)] -> Maybe UID` ; If you really want this, you'll have to create a type class containing "`go :: [(String,String)] -> Maybe a`" and make instances for your types.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I forgot to put the read in that I put in my test code.  It is edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html), I suspect you could end up with code like this:

```
makeGo ''FullName
```

that expands to

```
goFullName :: [(String, String)] -> Maybe FullName
goFullName fvs = do
  first  <- lookup "first_name" fvs
  middle <- lookup "middle_name" fvs
  last   <- lookup "last_name" fvs
  return $ FullName first middle last
```

---

An aside: if you `import Control.Applicative`, `goFullName` could be written more concisely, like this:

```
goFullName :: [(String, String)] -> Maybe FullName
goFullName fvs
   = FullName <$> lookup "first_name" fvs
              <*> lookup "middle_name" fvs
              <*> lookup "last_name" fvs
```

Comment: I thought about applicative, and I guess that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: @mindreader - you might be interested in 'idiom brackets', which provide some syntactic sugar for applicatives.  There are a few type-class-based implementations (to which I prefer standard notation, but YMMV), and also the Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement, known affectionately as 'SHE'.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this function as

```
import Control.Applicative

go :: [(String, String)] -> Maybe FullName
go fvs = FullName <$> l "first_name" <*> l "middle_name" <*> l "last_name"
    where l field = lookup field fvs
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to end up with `QueryResults` instances, why not just do something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,OverloadedStrings #-}

Module Main where

import Database.MySQL.Simple
import Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryResults
import Database.MySQL.Simple.Result
import Database.MySQL.Simple.Param

data FullName =
  FullName {
       first_name  :: String
     , middle_name :: String
     , last_name   :: String
  } deriving Show

newtype UID = UID Integer deriving (Show,Param)

instance QueryResults FullName where
  convertResults fs@[_,_,_] vs@[_,_,_] = FullName first middle last
    where [first,middle,last] = zipWith convert fs vs
  convertResults fs vs  = convertError fs vs 3

instance QueryResults UID where
  convertResults fs@[fuid] vs@[vuid] = UID (convert fuid vuid)
  convertResults fs vs  = convertError fs vs 1

uidToFullName :: UID -> IO FullName
uidToFullName (UID uid) =
  do conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
     [fn] <- query conn
         "SELECT first_name,middle_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid = ?" [uid]
     return fn
```

A sample session:

```
λ> :load Main.sh
λ> uidToFullName (UID 23)
FullName {first_name = "John", middle_name = "Horatio", last_name = "Smith"}
```

Here is the accompanying SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
  uid Integer PRIMARY KEY,
  email Text,
  first_name Text,
  middle_name Text,
  last_name Text
);

INSERT INTO user VALUES (23,'john.horation@smith.com','John','Horatio','Smith');
```

Comment: The reason I don't want to do it that way is that I want to be able to do a select with columns in any order, so long as they are properly named and there enough of them such that I will get valid type from it.  To do that I have to have convertResults not care about order of its arguments.